# Selenium - сайт отдаёт капчу при запуске скрипта на сервере

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenoid

Заранее прошу прощения, в теме только обучаюсь и это первый адекватный проект.

Суть в чём, один и тот же код отлично исполняется если я запускаю его локально, никаких проблем
Но когда я запускаю скрипт внутри Selenoid который находится на сервере в облаке - сайт постоянно выдаёт капчу

В связи с чем появился вопрос, как это можно пофиксить?
Есть ощущение что это блок по какому-то диапазону IP-адресов, но против этой гипотезы говорит то, что пару раз, случайно сайт меня всё таки пропустил.

Использовал вот такие опции при запуске (всё брал из интернетов в попытках наобум решить проблему):

```
ua = UserAgent()
us_ag = ua.chrome

capabilities = {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "version": "83.0",
        "enableVNC": True,
        "enableVideo": False
    }

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={us_ag}")
options.add_argument("window-size=1280,800")
```

Comment: я как-то делал парсер на селениуме и тоже столкнулся с капчей на блокчейн сайте. Если сайт динамически через js генерит контент, то вариант идти на сайты, у которых есть api для разгадывания капч. Это платно и медленно в рамках парсинга. Если не динамически, то можешь попробовать через requests спарсить html, если только он нужен

Comment: Сайт на реакте, разгадывать капчу вариант, спасибо. Но пока интересно разобраться так, как минимум прокси наверное подешевле будет - надо лишь понять нужен ли мне прокси или можно справиться самостоятельно

Comment: Прокси, подмена печенек - толковый сайт все равно понимает, что работает selenium и выдаст капчу. Ну, по крайней мере у меня так было. Обойти её без платного варианта не получилось, а платный медленный для меня, возможно, есть другие варианты

Comment: Суть в том что одновременно тот же самый скрипт работает без проблем на локальном ПК, следовательно подозреваю что резидентская прокся должна работать. Но это лишь предположение

Comment: Попробуй. Исходя из того, что я делал, конкретно в селениуме может случиться всё. Например, когда я пытался спарсить через селениум предметы на площадке, он выдавал html без предметов. Оказалось, что сайт динамически генерировал эти предметы. Стоило только написать time.sleep(5) для того, чтобы он увидел предметы. И таких нюансов я встретил не один. Поэтому можешь попробовать с бесплатным прокси поколдовать - может что-то получиться, или кто-то другой ответит. Удачи

Comment: Раз сайт динамический и требуется селениум то стоит посмотреть что под капотом у этого сайта, какие сетевые запросы он выполняет при открытии страницы. В 90% случаев удается забыть про парсинг и обращаться напрямую к API сайта за готовыми данными, где никаких капч уже нет (ну кроме случая что код капчи отдается в тот самый api, но это достаточно редки вариант)

Comment: Однажды у меня получалось с небольшим сервисом такое провернуть, но там ответы приходили обычным json-ом на ~100к товаров на сайте.

К сожалению в реакте не разбираюсь от слова совсем, а js знаю на очень базовом уровне (селениум на питоне пишу). 
Поэтому тут с моими компетенциями разобраться не получилось.

P.S. Я поднял прокси и всё стало работать

Comment: В 90% случаев читать js код вообще не нужно. запускаете хром, открываете консоль разработчика, идете на вкладку "Сеть", перегружаете изучаемую страницу. На вкладке видите все запросы которые отправлялись со всеми данными которые пришли в ответ. Включаете на вкладке фильтр "Fetch/XHR" перед вами только те запросы, которые были порождены JS кодом страницы, API запросы обычно все там

Comment: Спасибо, полезно, нашёл опять такой же JSON со всей нужной мне инфой, видимо в прошлый раз его пропустил

Comment: Таки и у меня капча внутри API вернулась :)

Comment: @АндрейЧевозёров Попробуй safari или firefox браузеры на https://playwright.dev/python/. Ещё рекомендую попробовать user-agent мобилки а именно айфонов, я так cloudflare обошёл. Скинь сайт, потестим.